# 'Folder' object has no attribute 'get_deferred_fields' when trying to create folder in django-cms filer

Tags: django, django-cms, django-filer

I created a plugin with a field in models:

```
picture = FilerImageField(related_name="gallery_image")
```

Now, when I try to add the plugin to a placeholder, window opens when I can add a picture. So I click "Add file" and new page opens with a list of uploaded files (empty right now). On that page I click create catalogue, enter it's name and when I click save the error shows up:

```
AttributeError at /pl/admin/filer/folder/make_folder/
'Folder' object has no attribute 'get_deferred_fields'
```

Django 1.7.9
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue, where it was not working on my test environment and it worked correctly on my local environment.

A few things that were not in sync. One of them was the django-mptt. In my test it was 0.8.7 and in my local I had it as 0.6.1. To test it out I updated my local, which upgrade my django to 1.9, which broke everything. So I reverted Django to 1.7.9 and mptt to 0.6.1. Also I updated my Pillow to 3.1.1.

So basically it is a combination if installing the plug in and making sure your requirements file has the right versions.

Answer (score 3):

> AttributeError at /pl/admin/filer/folder/make_folder/
>   'Folder' object has no attribute 'get_deferred_fields'

The reason for this is a mismatch between Django 1.7 and the django-mptt version. Django 1.8 introduced [`get_deferred_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_deferred_fields), and django-mptt-0.8.0 dropped support for Django < 1.8.

If you are running Django < 1.8, the last supported version for django-mptt is 0.7.4.

```
pip install django-mptt==0.7.4
```

Caution: Since Django 1.7 is not officially supported any longer, the safest option of course is to upgrade to Django 1.8 (LTS).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using d the library [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt). Then I upgraded from django 1.7.11 to 1.8.11 and worked very well.

Comment: I think it's not django. I upgraded from 1.7.9 to 1.9 and the error still exists.